# How to Print the largest rectangle in the matrix using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

/*Given a matrix

```
1 0 0 1 0       
0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0       
1 0 1 0 1
```

how to Print the largest rectangle in the matrix if any,  using javascript.

Output:

```
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: tried but did not get any solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Looks like you've forgot to add a question

Comment: What is "largest rectangle"? I think, given no other restrictions, that the largest rectangle is the matrix itself, isn't it?

Comment: all four corners of 1

Comment: yeah all four corners have 1